# How to use curl instead of url fopen?

Tags: php, curl, fopen

I am using the following codes but in my server `allow_url_fopen` is turned off for security reason. How to do this using curl.

```
     $request = array(
                    'method' => $method,
                    'params' => $params,
                    'id' => $currentId
                    );
    $request = json_encode($request);
    $this->debug && $this->debug.='***** Request *****'."\n".$request."\n".'***** End Of request *****'."\n\n";

    // performs the HTTP POST
    $opts = array ('http' => array (
                        'method'  => 'POST',
                        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/json',
                        'content' => $request
                        ));
    $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
    if ($fp = fopen($this->url, 'r', false, $context)) {
        $response = '';
        while($row = fgets($fp)) {
            $response.= trim($row)."\n";
        }
        $this->debug && $this->debug.='***** Server response *****'."\n".$response.'***** End of server response *****'."\n";
        $response = json_decode($response,true);
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Unable to connect to '.$this->url);
    }
```

Comment: [Start by reading this](http://php.net/curl) then come back when you have a concrete question to ask and not just a "write this for me please"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                 $request = array(
                    'method' => $method,
                    'params' => $params,
                    'id' => $currentId
                    );
    $request = json_encode($request);
    $this->debug && $this->debug.='***** Request *****'."\n".$request."\n".'***** End Of request *****'."\n\n";

    // performs the HTTP POST

      $ch = curl_init($this->url);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
            $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);
            curl_close($ch);
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function I wrote for this purpose which might help you. Be careful though, because it is not adjusted to your specific usecase.

```
<?php
/**
 * @param $base     First part of the URL to direct the request to
 * @param $path     Second part of the URL
 * @param $param    Array of parameters to be used for the request
 * @return          The result of the request if successful otherwise false
 */
function request($base = "", $path = "", $param = array()) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = $base . $path;
    if (isset($param["get"])) {
        $getparams = implode("&", $param["get"]);
        $url .= "?" . $getparams;
    }
    if (isset($param["post"])) {
        $postparams = implode("&", $param["post"]);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postparams);
    }
    if (isset($param["header"])) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $param["header"]);
    }
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_URL => $url
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;
}

$result = request("http://www.iana.org/domains/example/");
var_dump($result);

?>
```

Comment: There is an issue within this code

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PRIVATE on line 8` Why are you showing a private function outside a class?

Comment: @DainisAbols Because it is from a class of which the rest does not matter in this case and I forgot to remove the `private` part. Sorry about that.